# Bootstrap carousel went chaos

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with basic bootstrap carousel. I just want slides to move every four seconds, for example. Carousel looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    fixCarousel();
});

function fixCarousel() {
$('.carousel').carousel({
   interval: 1000*4
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x150" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption car_slide">
          <h3 class="slide_text">Suppliers of skilled Workforce</h3>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">
          <button class="learn_more_button btn btn-primary">
            LEARN MORE
          </button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x150" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption car_slide">
          <h3>SMART, EFFECTIVE ENTERPRISE SOLUTIONS</h3>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">
          <button class="learn_more_button btn btn-primary">
            LEARN MORE
          </button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

But strange things are happening. It works one time, another it waits like 10 sec, then few seconds, then, it goes normally, then, it stops cycling at all...

Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle, or even better, a StackSnippet within your question, which demonstrates the issue? Seemingly random or "chaotic" behaviour, as you put it, is generally not random, because computers are inherently not random. There will be a logical reason, but it will help to have a usable example to work from.

Comment: The behavior seems to be expected in the snippet.  I've watched this carousel like a hawk, waiting for any errant pixel, but none have been observed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/zj6bj6cj/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
     interval: 1000*4
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 300px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x15" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption car_slide">
          <h3 class="slide_text">Suppliers of skilled Workforce</h3>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">
          <button class="learn_more_button btn btn-primary">
            LEARN MORE
          </button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x15" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption car_slide">
          <h3>SMART, EFFECTIVE ENTERPRISE SOLUTIONS</h3>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">
          <button class="learn_more_button btn btn-primary">
            LEARN MORE
          </button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @GoldenEgg25... What issue you are facing??? Any error??? Please explain the situation will definitely help you out.  Is your website is live???

Comment: This JS code about carousel is not working. No matter what parameter I set. I've tried also editing the div parameter "internal". Every time I'm refershing the page I'm getting other effect. Once it's going every four seconds, once it stops, once it goes by eight.

Comment: Try this out https://jsfiddle.net/zj6bj6cj/1/ .... <div class="carousel" data-interval="4000"> . Instead of doing the interval in JavaScript do it as HTML5  data attribute.

Comment: I've tried this before. It works, but sometimes. That is chaos I'm talking about. After few refreshes, the carosuel stops to spin at all. And first spin is always longer than the others.

Comment: @GoldenEgg25 something else on your page is interfering with your code then. Watch your browser's console and network tab carefully for any activity/errors that you don't expect. You could also remove other bits of script on the page until it works as expected, to find the conflict. Like I asked previously, if you can make a fiddle based on your website, which demonstrates the problem actually happening, we might be able to help fix it.